# mypy complains about classmethod

Tags: python, mypy, pydantic

I have a trivial dataclass (from pydantic)

```
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

from abc import ABCMeta
from abc import abstractmethod


@dataclass
class BaseEntity(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def from_dict(cls, other: dict):
        ...

    @abstractmethod
    def dict(self):
        ...


@dataclass
class UserEntity(BaseEntity):
    id: Optional[str]
    name: str
    email: str
    avatar: str

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, other: dict):
        return cls(
            id=other.get("id"),
            name=other.get("name"),
            email=other.get("email"),
            avatar=other.get("avatar"),
        )
```

When I run mypy, I get this set of errors:

> app/entities/user.py:25: error: Unexpected keyword argument "id" for "UserEntity"  [call-arg]

> app/entities/user.py:25: error: Unexpected keyword argument "name" for "UserEntity"  [call-arg]

> app/entities/user.py:25: error: Unexpected keyword argument "email" for "UserEntity"  [call-arg]

> app/entities/user.py:25: error: Unexpected keyword argument "avatar" for "UserEntity"  [call-arg]

What I'm doing wrong? The code is fine; it runs. Or is it a mypy bug?

```
$ mypy --version
mypy 1.0.0 (compiled: yes)
```

Comment: Using the official [**mypy plugin**](https://docs.pydantic.dev/mypy_plugin/) for Pydantic should fix this.

Comment: I don't use Pydantic myself, but `BaseEntity.dict` doesn't seem to be relevant to the problem, so you could remove it for the sake of an MRE.

Comment: @wjandrea they asked me to include

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same code with the standard library `dataclasses` module is fine.

The problem is that given the class definition alone, there is no indication that `UserEntity.__init__` will accept *any* arguments, positional or keyword, because the only statically defined `__init__` for `mypy` to check against is `object.__init__`.

However, `mypy` is coded to know about `dataclasses` from the standard library, and in particular what to expect from the decorator `dataclasses.dataclass`, so that it can recognize that there *will* be an `__init__` method that has `id`, `name`, etc. as parameters.

This special treatment does not apply to `pydantic.dataclasses`, however.

Comment: Now makes sense to me

Comment: Note: There is a Pydantic [**plugin** for mypy](https://docs.pydantic.dev/mypy_plugin/), which also provides support for their variation of dataclasses.

Comment: I wondered; seemed like there should be some support, but I didn't look.

Comment: Nice to know @DaniilFajnberg. I'm adding it now to my project.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the constructor `from_dict` is supposed to call.

```
def __init__(self, id, name, email, avatar):                                                                                      
        self.id = id                                                                                                                  
        self.name = name                                                                                                              
        self.email = email                                                                                                            
        self.avatar = avatar
```

Comment: But it is a dataclass; there is no need for it.

Comment: The dataclass supplies it *dynamically*, not statically. `mypy` is hard-coded to know about the `dataclasses` module in the standard library, but not the third-party module provided by `pydantic`, even if the interface is compatible.